# How to check the current time if it is between two times using momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

> This question was asked several times before but I'm stuck!

what I tried to do

```
    let now = moment().format('LT'); // 11:28 PM
    let close = moment('2019-04-26T22:00:18.000Z').format('LT'); // 1:00 AM
    let open = moment('2019-04-26T13:00:32.000Z').format('LT'); // 4:00 PM
    console.log(moment(now).isBetween(moment(open), moment(close))); // always return false
    console.log(moment(now).isBetween(moment(open), moment(close), "hour")); // always return false
    console.log(moment(now).isBetween(open, close, "hour")); // always return false
    console.log(moment(now).isBetween(open, close)); // always return false
```

Any idea why I'm getting always false?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compare times, you can create a moment object at a certain hour and minute, and the other settings will default to today. Calling .format will return a string but doesn't modify the calling object. Your code is comparing today's date and time against times on a different day altogether, so it is always false. Also, there is no need to wrap a moment object in another call to Moment.

```js
// Opening and Closing Time data objects
const openingTime = {
    hour: 8,
    minute: 00
  },
  closingTime = {
    hour: 20,
    minute: 00
  };

// Create Moment objects
const now = moment(),
  openToday = moment(openingTime),
  openYesterday = moment(openingTime).subtract(1, 'day'),
  closeToday = moment(closingTime),
  closeTomorrow = moment(closingTime).add(1, 'day');

let openForBusiness = false;

if (openToday.isBefore(closeToday)) {
  openForBusiness = now.isBetween(openToday, closeToday);
} else {
  openForBusiness = now.isBetween(openYesterday, closeToday) || now.isBetween(openToday, closeTomorrow);
}

console.log("openForBusiness:", openForBusiness);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is not work in some cases like: let suppose now @ 1:12 Am and close @ 2:12 Am and open @ 8:12 Am isBetween return false. try it.

Comment: If you want to have open and close on separate days, you would need to make comparisons between both late yesterday and early today, and late today and early the next day. If open and close change, you can use moment's isAfter method, as in `if( open.isAfter( close ) )` to see if you need to do those types of comparisons. Moment also has convenient add and subtract methods to help create the previous and next day objects. If you try coding it and you have trouble, I'd create a new question

Comment: Please can you add new answer @JasonB

Comment: Updated algorithm to handle case when open and close are on different days.

Comment: this is not working for the following case https://jsfiddle.net/ykaz7p3h/1/, which is mean open 1am and close 2am always return true @JasonB

Comment: Oops, you are right, I have the order mixed up, `closeToday.isBefore(openToday)` should be `openToday.isBefore(closeToday)`. I'll update it now